# client side validation

Tags: 7, users, forms

I am trying to enable client side validation on my web forms. I installed & enabled the modules as per the Drupal.org link:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1324924
& then went into the Configuration > Client Side Validation & inserted the form ids I had in my HTML code.

However, I am unable to get the client side validation to work (errors are not recognised in the input fields), the attached screenshot shows the modules view.

The only module that seems to be missing is the 'IFE' module which I cannot find / install.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You may do this through custom code...

Comment: Notice that you are simply stating facts without asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work fine with implicit questions. In the case you were asking where to find the IFE module, that would be off-topic for us.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download, install and enable the [**IFE**](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife)  (aka. "Inline Form Errors") module.

Like all Drupal modules, its project page is immediately below `https://www.drupal.org/project/`.

Here is a link to the project page where you can download it:  [IFE project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife).

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [Field Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) module in case of content type. If you are using webform module then use [Webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation)